# UIautomatorviewer Java Home issue

Tags: java, appium, android-uiautomator

I am having a problem opening uiautomatorviewer on mac.

This is what I get on the terminal when I issue the command uiautomatorviewer:

```
???@???-MacBook-Pro-2 libexec % uiautomatorviewer
SWT folder '/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/4333796/tools/lib/
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/libexec/java_home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.' does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined JAVA_HOME in your system path. To do this:

- Open Terminal
- Confirm you have JDK by typing “which java”. It should show something like /usr/bin/java.
- Check you have the needed version of Java, by typing “java -version”.

JAVA_HOME is essentially the full path of the directory that contains a sub-directory named bin which in turn contains the java.

For Mac OSX – it is: `/Library/Java/Home`

- Set JAVA_HOME using this command in Terminal: `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home`
- `echo $JAVA_HOME` on Terminal to confirm the path

You should now be able to run your application

**Note that this sets JAVA_HOME only for this session. If you want it to persist, you will have to add the command to your ~/.profile file.  Below are instructions on how to accomplish this instead:**

- Open up Terminal.app (Applications >> Utilities >> Terminal)
- Type: `emacs .profile`
- add this to the end of the .profile file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export JAVA_HOME;
```

- Save and exit emacs `(ctrl-x, ctrl-s; ctrl-x, ctrl-c)`
- Open a new Terminal window (cmd-n) and type: `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version`

If you see something like:

```
java version “1.8.0_16″
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.8.0_16-b06-284)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.8.0_16-133, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Then you’ve successfully set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to the binary stored in /Library/Java/Home/bin/java

Source: [SajeConsultants](http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the detailed answer, however, I seem to have the same issue. I am using a Mac. Currently, .bash_profile contains the following ```# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH```.

Comment: Also, this is what I did as you mentioned: in the terminal I enter the following commands: ```export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home``` and then ```echo $JAVA_HOME```, after that I run my uiautomatorviewer like this on terminal ```/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer```. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: Additionally, if I run uiautomator directly from terminal I get this message:
```
-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```